# python cmd module parse multiple arguments with spaces in it

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python script that will submit my id and filename and retrieve some info based on the filename. The "Cmd" module should prompt me for both an id and filename. However, so far this is the script that I have written. I have to manually type in my id in the script and once I run this script, it prompts me for a filename. Is there any way in which I can make this script to prompt me for both id and filename (and what if the filename contains spaces).

```
import requests
from cmd import Cmd


class Term(Cmd):

    prompt = "promtp >>> "

    def default(self, args):
        id = "someid"
        resp = requests.post('http://10.10.10.10/login',
                headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
                data={"username": name, "filename": f"{args}"})

    def do_quit(self, args):
        return 1

term = Term()
term.cmdloop()
```

The part where the filename contains space is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When typing your name in the prompt, also type you id, like this:

`promtp >>> your_name your_id`

The args in the default method is actually a string, so you should change for singular, like `arg`.

Then, you have to split the string in arg so you can get the two words passed at the command line. Like this:

```py
    def default(self, arg):
        
        args = arg.split()
        name = args[0]
        id = args[1]
```

You could also use the `argparse` module to simplify parsing more complex scenarios.

Here is an example for parsing a file name with spaces and an id:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(dest='filename', action='append', type=str)
parser.add_argument(dest='id', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.filename)
print(args.id)
```

Now execute from the command line (notice I've used '' around the 'My File Name'):

```sh
> python3 .\example.py 'My File Name' 10        
['My File Name']
10
```

Comment: That's good. If I am right, the filename can't contain spaces.

Comment: @Stevey, you can use the argparse module. It's included with Python.